# Can non-watchface Android Wear apps display indicators? (battery level, connection status cloud icon, etc)

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm working on a Wear app with a few buttons that send commands to an app on the handheld via the MessageApi.  I'm using the DataApi to share data between the watch and handheld.  As a result, my Wear activity knows the Node ID that provided the data being displayed.  Using a NodeApi.NodeListener, I can detect if/when the handheld device disconnects.   What should happen if it does?  I stop sending the messages in response to button clicks since I don't want them queued and delivered later if the connection is restored.  As a result, the buttons appear to simply not work. I'd like to display the "disconnected cloud" icon one might see on a watchface.  Is there a way to add watchface indicators to a non-watchface activity?﻿I realize I can add my own message or icon to my layout but I'd prefer to use the same indicator the user sees elsewhere.

Comment: For future readers: although the actual status indicators are not available directly, Google has the icons up on GitHub.  So you can use a NodeListener and the actual icon to get more or less the same result.

For example:  https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/file/drawable-hdpi/ic_cloud_off_black_24dp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own icon. The icons you mention are only displayed on the launcher activity, on top of the watch face (wallpaper).

Comment: Unfortunately this does seem to be the answer.  It would be really handy if the battery/charging/connectivity status bar gizmo was available for any activity to display.